Alternative to EXPANDING NESTED TABLES on old version of ABAP?
As one probably knows we have such handy clause of MOVE-CORRESPONDING as EXPANDING NESTED TABLES:
MOVE-CORRESPONDING: <m_source> TO <m_target> EXPANDING NESTED TABLES.

What it basically does is resolves table and structure types on every level of hierarchy if they do not match 1:1 but have common fields and line types. And this is exactly what I need on my current project: I have 7-10 levels of hierarchy of proxy structures that I need to copy to each other.
The problem is my system is ABAP 7.31 SP 10, so this clause is unavailable for me. I can easily invent some creepy RTTS construction like this (schematically):
 LOOP AT <m_source>-components ASSIGNING <fs_components_l0>.
    LOOP AT <fs_components_l0>-components ASSIGNING <fs_components_l1>.
    ....
     DO N TIMES.
      ASSIGN COMPONENT n OF STRUCTURE <fs_components_l1> to <fs_components_l1_comp>.
      MOVE-CORRESPONDING ...
     ENDDO.
    ENDLOOP.
 ENDLOOP.

but that can be very verbose with multiple levels of hierarchy, and not very maintainable.
Anybody ever invented more neat and effective replacement of EXPANDING NESTED TABLES?

I don't consider it "creepy" (as you say) if you use RTTS and recursive programming. The code would be quite maintainable.
The class is named lcl_move_corresponding_nested, here's how to use it:
lcl_move_corresponding_nested=>process( EXPORTING source = structure1
                                        IMPORTING target = structure2 ).

This is the code:
CLASS lcx_move_corresponding_nested DEFINITION INHERITING FROM cx_static_check.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_move_corresponding_nested DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS process
      IMPORTING source TYPE any
      EXPORTING target TYPE any
      RAISING lcx_move_corresponding_nested.

  PRIVATE SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS process_structure
      IMPORTING !source TYPE any
      EXPORTING !target TYPE any
      RAISING   lcx_move_corresponding_nested.

    CLASS-METHODS process_itab
      IMPORTING !source TYPE ANY TABLE
      EXPORTING !target TYPE ANY TABLE
      RAISING   lcx_move_corresponding_nested.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_move_corresponding_nested IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD process.
    DATA source_rtts TYPE REF TO cl_abap_datadescr.
    DATA target_rtts TYPE REF TO cl_abap_datadescr.

    source_rtts ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( source ).
    target_rtts ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( target ).
    IF source_rtts->kind <> target_rtts->kind.
      RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE lcx_move_corresponding_nested.
    ENDIF.
    CASE source_rtts->kind.
      WHEN cl_abap_typedescr=>kind_table.
        process_itab( EXPORTING source = source
                      IMPORTING target = target ).
      WHEN cl_abap_typedescr=>kind_struct.
        process_structure( EXPORTING source = source
                           IMPORTING target = target ).
      WHEN OTHERS.
        target = source.
    ENDCASE.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD process_structure.
    DATA source_rtts_structure TYPE REF TO cl_abap_structdescr.
    DATA source_component      TYPE REF TO abap_compdescr.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS <source_component> TYPE any.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS <target_component> TYPE any.

    CLEAR target.
    source_rtts_structure ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( source ).
    LOOP AT source_rtts_structure->components REFERENCE INTO source_component.
      ASSIGN COMPONENT source_component->name OF STRUCTURE source TO <source_component>.
      ASSERT sy-subrc = 0.
      ASSIGN COMPONENT source_component->name OF STRUCTURE target TO <target_component>.
      IF sy-subrc <> 0.
        CONTINUE.
      ENDIF.
      process( EXPORTING source = <source_component>
               IMPORTING target = <target_component> ).
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD process_itab.
    DATA source_rtts_table       TYPE REF TO cl_abap_tabledescr.
    DATA ref_to_target_itab_line TYPE REF TO data.
    DATA source_rtts_table_line TYPE REF TO cl_abap_datadescr.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS <source_itab_line> TYPE any.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS <target_itab_line> TYPE any.

    CLEAR target.
    CREATE DATA ref_to_target_itab_line LIKE LINE OF target.
    ASSIGN ref_to_target_itab_line->* TO <target_itab_line>.
    source_rtts_table ?= cl_abap_typedescr=>describe_by_data( source ).
    LOOP AT source ASSIGNING <source_itab_line>.
      process( EXPORTING source = <source_itab_line>
               IMPORTING target = <target_itab_line> ).
      INSERT <target_itab_line> INTO TABLE target.
    ENDLOOP.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

Test data (works only from ABAP 7.40):
* Example data taken from DEMO_MOVE_CORRESPONDING_ITAB and enriched.
CLASS ltc_app DEFINITION
    FOR TESTING
    DURATION SHORT
    RISK LEVEL HARMLESS
    FINAL.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
    METHODS test   FOR TESTING RAISING cx_static_check.
    METHODS test_2 FOR TESTING RAISING cx_static_check.
    METHODS test_3 FOR TESTING RAISING cx_static_check.

    TYPES c3 TYPE c LENGTH 4.

    TYPES: BEGIN OF eline1,
             col1 TYPE c3,
             col2 TYPE c3,
           END OF eline1.

    TYPES: BEGIN OF eline2,
             col2 TYPE c3,
             col3 TYPE c3,
           END OF eline2.

    TYPES: BEGIN OF iline1,
             col1 TYPE c3,
             col2 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF eline1 WITH EMPTY KEY,
           END OF iline1.

    TYPES: BEGIN OF iline2,
             col2 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF eline2 WITH EMPTY KEY,
             col3 TYPE c3,
           END OF iline2.

    TYPES: BEGIN OF line1,
             col1 TYPE c3,
             col2 TYPE c3,
             col3 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF iline1 WITH EMPTY KEY,
           END OF line1.

    TYPES: BEGIN OF line2,
             col2 TYPE c3,
             col3 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF iline2 WITH EMPTY KEY,
             col4 TYPE c3,
           END OF line2.

    TYPES ty_itab1 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF line1 WITH EMPTY KEY.
    TYPES ty_itab2 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF line2 WITH EMPTY KEY.

    DATA itab1 TYPE ty_itab1.
    DATA itab2 TYPE ty_itab2.

    METHODS fill_tables.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS ltc_app IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD fill_tables.
    itab1 = VALUE #(
      ( col1 = 'a11'
        col2 = 'a12'
        col3 = VALUE #( ( col1 = 'a11'  col2 = VALUE #( ( col1 = 'a11' col2 = 'a12' )
                                                        ( col1 = 'a21' col2 = 'a22' ) ) )
                        ( col1 = 'a21'  col2 = VALUE #( ( col1 = 'a11' col2 = 'a12' )
                                                        ( col1 = 'a21' col2 = 'a22' ) ) ) ) )
      ( col1 = 'b21'
        col2 = 'b22'
        col3 = VALUE #( ( col1 = 'b11'  col2 = VALUE #( ( col1 = 'b11' col2 = 'b12' )
                                                        ( col1 = 'b21' col2 = 'b22' ) ) )
                        ( col1 = 'b21'  col2 = VALUE #( ( col1 = 'b11' col2 = 'b12' )
                                                        ( col1 = 'b21' col2 = 'b22' ) ) ) ) )
      ( col1 = 'c31'
        col2 = 'c32'
        col3 = VALUE #( ( col1 = 'c11'  col2 = VALUE #( ( col1 = 'c11' col2 = 'c12' )
                                                        ( col1 = 'c21' col2 = 'c22' ) ) )
                        ( col1 = 'c21'  col2 = VALUE #( ( col1 = 'c11' col2 = 'c12' )
                                                        ( col1 = 'c21' col2 = 'c22' ) ) ) ) ) ).

    itab2 = VALUE #(
      ( col2 = 'x11'
        col3 = VALUE #( ( col3 = 'x12'  col2 = VALUE #( ( col2 = 'x12' )
                                                        ( col2 = 'x22' ) ) )
                        ( col3 = 'x22'  col2 = VALUE #( ( col2 = 'x12' )
                                                        ( col2 = 'x22' ) ) )
                        ( col3 = 'x32'  col2 = VALUE #( ( col2 = 'x12' )
                                                        ( col2 = 'x22' ) ) ) )
        col4 = 'x12' )
      ( col2 = 'y21'
        col3 = VALUE #( ( col3 = 'y12' )
                        ( col3 = 'y22' )
                        ( col3 = 'y32' ) )
        col4 = 'y22' ) ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD test.
    data itab2_custom type ty_itab2.
    data itab2_standard type ty_itab2.
    fill_tables( ).
    lcl_move_corresponding_nested=>process( EXPORTING source = itab1
                                            IMPORTING target = itab2_custom ).
    MOVE-CORRESPONDING itab1 TO itab2_standard EXPANDING NESTED TABLES.
    cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_equals( act = itab2_custom
                                        exp = itab2_standard ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD test_2.
    TYPES ty_itab2 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF string WITH EMPTY KEY.
    DATA itab1          TYPE TABLE OF string WITH EMPTY KEY.
    DATA itab2_custom   TYPE ty_itab2.
    DATA itab2_standard TYPE ty_itab2.

    itab1 = VALUE #( ( `A` ) ).
    lcl_move_corresponding_nested=>process( EXPORTING source = itab1
                                            IMPORTING target = itab2_custom ).
    MOVE-CORRESPONDING itab1 TO itab2_standard EXPANDING NESTED TABLES.
    cl_abap_unit_assert=>assert_equals( act = itab2_custom
                                        exp = itab2_standard ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD test_3.
    TYPES:
      BEGIN OF ty_struct1,
        a TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF string WITH EMPTY KEY,
      END OF ty_struct1.
    TYPES:
      BEGIN OF ty_struct2,
        a TYPE i,
      END OF ty_struct2.
    DATA struct1          TYPE ty_struct1.
    DATA struct2_custom   TYPE ty_struct2.
    DATA struct2_standard TYPE ty_struct2.
    FIELD-SYMBOLS <struct2_standard> TYPE any.

    " MOVE-CORRESPONDING struct1 TO struct2_standard EXPANDING NESTED TABLES.
    " Syntax error: "The identically named component "STRUCT1[]-TY_STRUCT1-A"
    "                cannot be converted to "STRUCT2_STANDARD[]-TY_STRUCT2-A".
    "
    " ASSIGN struct2_standard TO <struct2_standard>.
    " MOVE-CORRESPONDING struct1 TO <struct2_standard> EXPANDING NESTED TABLES.
    " Short dump: OBJECTS_MOVE_NOT_SUPPORTED
    "             Conversion of type "TABLE OF STRING" to type "I" not supported.
    TRY.
        lcl_move_corresponding_nested=>process( EXPORTING source = struct1
                                                IMPORTING target = struct2_custom ).
        cl_abap_unit_assert=>fail( msg = 'should have failed' ).
      CATCH lcx_move_corresponding_nested ##NO_HANDLER.
    ENDTRY.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

